# check validity of url using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How to use javascript and check if a link is from a particular website or not?

eg:

If website=http://youtube.com/ajshdas

if option= youtube

```
 <html>
 <select>
 <option>Youtube</option>
 .......
 </html>
```

how do i use javascript to validate this? Should i use regex? If so how is it done in javascript? I am using back end to check this, is it good to check using front end scripting or backend scripting?

Update: I need the user to select from a list of 10 websites and submit a link a text box below.

Comment: if website=..., if option=youtube, then you want what to happen?

Comment: From the perspective of the user, why would I have to enter an url AND select an option? If I enter "youtube.com", your application should be able to figure out what website I would have selected. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try Splitting the string using the string function and delimiter to extract out "youtube" from  https://www.youtube.com by taking delimiter as "." and then checking that string in the website Name String by using a function .contains.

There are many other ways also.This is just a basic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Input should always be validated on the back-end to ensure correctness of your application (malicious users can easily circumvent front-end validation).

Input should preferably be validated on the front-end as well, to improve the user experience (not having to reload a page).

In javascript:

```
var url= document.createElement('a');
url.href = "http://youtube.com/ajshdas";

url.protocol == "http:";
url.hostname == "youtube.com";
url.pathname == "/ajshdas";
```

I don't know your usecase, but instead of a `<select>` input, you could simply extract your hostname from your url input.